# properly express the node range from 3 to 10

Tags: xpath

In w3c web ,we have some expression  such as

```
/bookstore/book[1]  
/bookstore/book[last()]     
/bookstore/book[last()-1]   
/bookstore/book[position()<3]
```

If there are 20  son nodes of bookstore,that is `book` ,i want to get the nodes from 3 to 10,how can i express it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as it is:

```
/bookstore/book[position()>=3 and position()<=10]
```