# xpath expression to match range of positions or subset of positions

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

From this site http://www.gwblawfirm.com/contact-us/ the xpath call below extracts 24 elements.  But I only want the four city elements (Anderson, Charlotte, Columbia, and Greenville -- 12:15).  If the state comes along wit the city that is OK.

```
require(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.gwblawfirm.com/contact-us/', useInternal = TRUE)        
xpathSApply(doc, "//ul[@class='menu']/li/a", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
 [1] "Home"              "About"             "Staff"             "Abnormal Use Blog" "Contact Us"       
 [6] "Attorneys"         "Practice Areas"    "Industries"        "News"              "Resources"        
[11] "Career Center"     "Anderson, SC"      "Charlotte, NC"     "Columbia, SC"      "Greenville, SC"   
[16] "Home"              "Attorneys"         "Practice Areas"    "Industries"        "About"            
[21] "News"              "Career Center"     "Contact Us"        "Disclaimer"
```

This question suggested the following, but it returns all 24.
[properly express the node range from 3 to 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591184/properly-express-the-node-range-from-3-to-10)

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//ul[@class='menu']/li/a[position()>=1 and position()<=16]", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
```

How can I match and return only the non-city elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets to identify `<a>` position within entire XPath result, otherwise `position()` recognized as local position within the same `<li>` parent node :

```
(//ul[@class='menu']/li/a)[position()>=12 and position()<=15]
```

A better option would be to get `<ul>` based on `<h2 class="widgettitle">Contact</h2>` tag :

```
//h2[@class='widgettitle' and .='Contact']/following-sibling::ul[@class='menu'][1]/li/a
```